# How to dynamically set the strokeStyle on moveTo and LintTo using canvas

Tags: html, angular, typescript, canvas, html5-canvas

I want the line should be draw with alternative stroke color like suppose i have predefined coordinates and I want to matching the pattern. If the line will not match then line stroke color should be red otherwise line should be white color if screen is black.

```
//HTLM PAGE 
 <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-6">
      <canvas #canvas1></canvas>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-6" id="figure">
      <canvas #canvas (mousedown)="startDrawing($event)" (mousemove)="drawLine($event)" (mouseup)="stopDrawing()"></canvas>
   </div>
</div>


//Typescript code
drawLinePattern() {
 for (const item of this.lines) {
    this.ctx.beginPath();
    this.ctx1.moveTo(item.px, item.py);
    this.ctx1.lineTo(item.x, item.y);
   if(this.lines.length % 2 == 0)
   this.ctx1.strokeStyle = 'white';
   else
   this.ctx1.strokeStyle = 'red';
   this.ctx1.stroke();
}
```